# Add deployment file to VS 2017 without deploying

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017

I just installed VS2017 and I want to deploy specific .js files without deploying the whole project. When I try to upload a new deployment file, VS force me to publish the project. Is it possible to just add a deployment file without deploying? So I can use that deployment file to deploy singles .js files or html files.

EDIT
Lets say I want to deploy a project to a virtual directory on Azure. For example to domain.com/newapp. Using a deployment file, I would like to first edit the settings, how am I supposed to do that, if VS2017 deploys the project immediately after I pick the deployment file.

Comment: How about using FTP for that?

Comment: If you want to deploy the single file,you could right click click the file to publish it.

Comment: correct. But it will deploy to the already settled deployment file. What if I want to deploy a single file using a different deployment file. See the edit to find another example